# CakePHP submitting forms: link vs post methods

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I'd like to obtain some opinions about using `link` vs `post` form method types. For example, if I have a controller `searches` that finds products at the URL `/searches/products`, there are two ways to make this work.

With the `link` method, I can grab the data from `$this->params['url']` as an array. With `post`, I can get them in `$this->params['form']` using hidden form elements. This is assuming I am not using the CakePHP Form Helper. With the `post` method, the search string can be an argument for the action, so it seems like the way to go, but when would you ever go with the `link` method when submitting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's actually a search, I would almost always go w/ the URL method.  It allows people to bookmark their results.

Comment: (You'll notice that's what all the major search engines to as well)